# Can we create a reference link in Rblogdown webpage

Tags: r

In R blogdown webpage, Can we create a reference link so that I only need to change the links in R file. For Example I will create Link1 and Link2 as shown below. So now can we render this Link1 and Link2 in R blogdown .md files, so once I change the links in the below document, the webpage should be rendered. Let say, In Config.toml file (of hugo-universal-theme) there is literally a facebook link. But I do not require this. I should only use this Link1 to render facebook page. Is it possible to achieve this?

[image]

Explaination

I will explain below. In the below .md file (from devcows/hugo-universal-theme), you can see the link for github right? So my question was, can we name as Link1 (see Fiq2). So this Link1 is actually https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases. This reference should be given in other file like shown in Fiq3

Fiq1
[image]

Fiq2
[image]

Fiq3

Link1= https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases

Link2 = https://facebook.com

Comment: Hi all. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: To me, it is really not clear what are you asking. Is this a question on updating Rmd to Markdown, or is this a question on Hugo templates? If it is Hugo related, maybe ask at https://discourse.gohugo.io/

Comment: I have edited my question. See the Explanation section